# Get Thin (bundle exec thin) to work with Circus

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, thin, circusd

I'm using Circus as my supervisor for a Rails project, but I'm having some weird problem to make it work with Thin, the Ruby Server I chose. This is my `circus.ini`:

```
[circus]
check_delay = 5

[socket:server]
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 8080

[watcher:server]
working_dir = /home/myuser/myproject/myproject
cmd = bundle exec thin start -C /home/myuser/myproject/etc/thin.yml -S $(circus.sockets.server)
use_sockets = True
numprocesses = 3

stdout_stream.class = FileStream
stdout_stream.filename = /home/myuser/myproject/log/circus_server.log
stdout_stream.time_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[env:server]
RAILS_ENV=production
```

But when I start circus (`sudo service circus start`), this is what I find on logs:

> $ cat log/circus.log
>   2014-06-03 10:42:27 circus[30987] [INFO] Starting master on pid 30987
>   2014-06-03 10:42:27 circus[30987] [INFO] sockets started
>   2014-06-03 10:42:27 circus[30987] [WARNING] error in 'server': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>   2014-06-03 10:42:27 circus[30987] [WARNING] error in 'server': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>   2014-06-03 10:42:27 circus[30987] [WARNING] error in 'server': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>   2014-06-03 10:42:27 circus[30987] [WARNING] error in 'server': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>   2014-06-03 10:42:27 circus[30987] [WARNING] error in 'server': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>   2014-06-03 10:42:27 circus[30987] [INFO] server stopped
>   2014-06-03 10:42:27 circus[30987] [INFO] Arbiter now waiting for commands

For a matter of fact, I changed `cmd` to any other command like `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and it worked. What's happening here?

EDIT: Here's [what happens](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lsmag/4028b01a88c0457f48a6/raw/81d1d3da8f4b0006aee28cf693d135839c7dec8e/run%20circus.ini) when I run circusd with `--log-level debug`... I still get the same output regardless of `copy_env = True` in my circus.ini.

Comment: Can you share your `etc/thin.yml`? I'm trying to let circus handle the socket and bind 3 thin processes, but all I am getting is the first binding `Listening on 0.0.0.0:137, CTRL+C to stop` and the other two getting a 'port in use' error.

Comment: `ps` output shows it trying to start thing with `thin -S 137`, is that really the correct way to bind the socket to the thin process?

Comment: Can thin even bind to already opened sockets like Circus does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` you're getting probably means that Circus isn't finding `bundle`.
You could try to add your RVM bin directory to your path, like that :

```
[env:server]
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/rvm/bin
```

The most likely folder you'll need is "wrappers", because it contains both ruby and gems scripts, so try it:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/.rvm/wrappers/<your ruby version>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue you have described.

Just add a `copy_env = True` to your [watcher:NAME] configuration:

```
[watcher:server]
working_dir = /home/myuser/myproject/myproject
cmd = bundle exec thin start -C /home/myuser/myproject/etc/thin.yml -S $(circus.sockets.server)
use_sockets = True
numprocesses = 3

stdout_stream.class = FileStream
stdout_stream.filename = /home/myuser/myproject/log/circus_server.log
stdout_stream.time_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

copy_env = True
```